# Converting NSDictionary to NSData using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a dictionary that looks like below

```
{
childViews =     (
            {
        childViews =             (
                            {
                childViews =                     (
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {80.166666666666671, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {160, 110}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {130, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 160}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {130, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 210}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {130, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 260}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {130, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 260}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {130.16666666666666, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 310}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {130, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 360}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {129.83333333333334, 20.166666666666668}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {210, 410}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                                                            {
                                        childViews =                                             (
                                        );
                                        properties =                                             {
                                            center = "NSPoint: {0, 0}";
                                        };
                                    }
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {207, 500.5}";
                                };
                            },
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {207, 671.83333333333326}";
                                };
                            },
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {409.83333333333337, 641}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {217, 368}";
                        };
                    },
                                            {
                        childViews =                             (
                                                            {
                                childViews =                                     (
                                );
                                properties =                                     {
                                    center = "NSPoint: {70, 29.833333333333336}";
                                };
                            }
                        );
                        properties =                             {
                            center = "NSPoint: {80, 716}";
                        };
                    }
                );
                properties =                     {
                    center = "NSPoint: {207, 368}";
                };
            }
        );
        properties =             {
            center = "NSPoint: {207, 368}";
        };
    }
);
properties =     {
    center = "NSPoint: {207, 368}";
};
```

}

When I try to convert this dictionary into NSData using code

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self toDictionary]
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
```

I get error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteValue)'
```

I need help in understanding the value that might be causing this crash.

Comment: You are take ResponseObjetct instedof [self toDictionary].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization), the only types which are directly convertible to JSON through `NSJSONSerialization` are arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, and null values. Your dictionaries contain `NSValue` instances which wrap `NSPoint`s, which are not convertible to JSON, thus the exception. You will need to replace those with one of the allowed types, either encoding points as an array of two values, a dictionary, a string, etc.

The reason this may not be clear from the description of your dictionary is that the `NSValue` instances are printed in quotes, but they are not actually strings — that is simply how they display.

Comment: That worked. Thank-you. Sometimes these po can take you in different direction altogether !

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a structure that contains arrays, dictionaries ("objects" in javascript), strings, numbers, and null (NSNUll).  You are trying to encode `NSPoint`s into JSON and JSON is not designed for that.  I suggest either converting the points to strings, or to objects (something like: {x:160, y:110}).

see also https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization for a full description of what objects can be converted to JSON.

Comment: But, is that not present in String - this is my confusion. Should it not have got encoded as is?

Comment: No, they are not strings. As Itai's pointed out they look like string in the logs but they are not strings.